# migrating from D3.js V3 to D3 V4 Error :Cannot read property 'baseVal' of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to convert this code https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3213173 into D3.js V4
,so i had to change some functions names like d3.svg.scale d3.svg.axis by the the new names in the d3 V4, but I still have some problems.
This time I receive the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseVal' of undefined

[image]

at Scatterplot.js:83 -> cell.call(brush); in my code

But I have no idea how to deal with it, so is there anyone faced the same problem or has a solution for this pb ?

This is the code in d3 V4 (maybe I forgot something to change)

```
node = new ReactFauxDOM.Element('svg');
var width = 960,
    size = 230,
    padding = 20;

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([padding / 2, size - padding / 2]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([size - padding / 2, padding / 2]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(x)
    .ticks(6);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(y)
    .ticks(6);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

d3.csv("../../tweets.csv", function (error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    var domainByTrait = {},
        traits = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function (d) { return d !== "species"; }),
        n = traits.length;

    traits.forEach(function (trait) {
        domainByTrait[trait] = d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d[trait]; });
    });

    xAxis.tickSize(size * n);
    yAxis.tickSize(-size * n);

    var brush = d3.brush()
        .on("start", brushstart)
        .on("brush", brushmove)
        .on("end", brushend);

    var svg = d3.select(node).append("svg")
        .attr("width", size * n + padding)
        .attr("height", size * n + padding)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + "," + padding / 2 + ")");

    svg.selectAll(".x.axis")
        .data(traits)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", function (d, i) { return "translate(" + (n - i - 1) * size + ",0)"; })
        .each(function (d) { x.domain(domainByTrait[d]); d3.select(this).call(xAxis); });

    svg.selectAll(".y.axis")
        .data(traits)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", function (d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * size + ")"; })
        .each(function (d) { y.domain(domainByTrait[d]); d3.select(this).call(yAxis); });

    var cell = svg.selectAll(".cell")
        .data(cross(traits, traits))
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "cell")
        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + (n - d.i - 1) * size + "," + d.j * size + ")"; })
        .each(plot);

    // Titles for the diagonal.
    cell.filter(function (d) { return d.i === d.j; }).append("text")
        .attr("x", padding)
        .attr("y", padding)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .text(function (d) { return d.x; });

    cell.call(brush);

    function plot(p) {
        var cell = d3.select(this);

        x.domain(domainByTrait[p.x]);
        y.domain(domainByTrait[p.y]);

        cell.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "frame")
            .attr("x", padding / 2)
            .attr("y", padding / 2)
            .attr("width", size - padding)
            .attr("height", size - padding);

        cell.selectAll("circle")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d[p.x]); })
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d[p.y]); })
            .attr("r", 4)
            .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.species); });
    }

    var brushCell;

    // Clear the previously-active brush, if any.
    function brushstart(p) {
        if (brushCell !== this) {
            d3.select(brushCell).call(brush.clear());
            x.domain(domainByTrait[p.x]);
            y.domain(domainByTrait[p.y]);
            brushCell = this;
        }
    }

    // Highlight the selected circles.
    function brushmove(p) {
        var e = brush.extent();
        svg.selectAll("circle").classed("hidden", function (d) {
            return e[0][0] > d[p.x] || d[p.x] > e[1][0]
                || e[0][1] > d[p.y] || d[p.y] > e[1][1];
        });
    }

    // If the brush is empty, select all circles.
    function brushend() {
        if (brush.empty()) svg.selectAll(".hidden").classed("hidden", false);
    }
```

Comment: look at var brush in a v4 graph.  Pretty sure you're going to need to be using brushX: http://bl.ocks.org/rajvansia/ce6903fad978d20773c41ee34bf6735c

Comment: I dont know how to use brushX and brush in general, so I used an example without brushing